# determine a model's default order by a field of its foreign key Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to order a model based on a field of its foreign key. I find results when googling this as to the ORM, but I'm before that, declaring the metaclass. They show things such as

```
 units = Unit.objecwhere to lookts.filter(color='red').order_by('location__label')
```

but I want to order on declaration automatically:

```
class Office(models.Model):
    objects = OfficeManager()
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='office_id', primary_key=True)
    office = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tblOffices'
        ordering = ('office',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.office


class OfficeCity(models.Model):
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office, db_column='tblOffices')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cities'
        ordering = ('office.description')
```

Is the above code snippet correct to order these cities by the FK description field? Thank you

Attached is a demo of a django learner's "googling it in less than or equal to 15 seconds", end quote.

[image]

[image]

Note that in the second picture, the django learner may be tempted to click on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/ and read the entire 26 pages (from if you were to print it), spending a few hours relearning useful things they've already read, but surely not finding an answer to the question by "googling it within 15 seconds". This leads one to believe that possibly the person who googled it within 15 seconds already knew *where to look* and *what to look for*, which is why it took them 15 seconds, but for the learner it would take several hours to find the answer. If the learner is not implementing this feature, but merely curious, it would seem a Q&A forum is the proper place to seek answers (the A part of Q&A) by positing questions (the Q part). Let's leave the ego to the brain surgeons guys, we understand if you've been doing this for 30 years you're an expert, those of us half your age learning this will be an expert when we're 60 too. Hopefully we remain humble, however...

Comment: You can always clone the project, point to a database you own and test with your own data. Relying on a Q&A site for the functionality of your code is a BAD idea...just saying.

Comment: I'm not going to implement this, the question is useful and the answer not easily found online...just saying.

Comment: I really don't understand why you cannot test it locally. All you need is 2 offices and 2 office cities. You could enter them via the admin or via a script (using factories).

Comment: I can't test here for the reason I stated, an example is here, `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')
`, I can't under the shell with that syntax `cs2.OfficeCity: (models.E015) 'ordering' refers to the non-existent field 'office.office'.` since my migration won't work since I can't change that db, and if you don't want to answer I'm not stalking you forcing you to answer!

Comment: we're spending more time speaking here than speaking about the question! and you "don't post anything on a question site" guys waste more time than it would take to answer everytime. if you aren't using django, move along and let a django expert answer, I'm trying to learn django better here. I'm not even implementing this I'm curious, hence the point of a forum

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect what's pertinent when people ask a question

Comment: "I'm trying to learn django better here." => great and we are trying to help you out. I've answered below but that doesn't matter much. If you want to progress, the first thing would be to get the project running locally. Good luck.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/ => 15 seconds search

Comment: the project is running locally guy! Thank you for your answer, and I hope you have a better today today than yesterday lol...

Comment: I don't think being great at software helped you or cdvv's communication skills much

Comment: codyc4321 at the matter of fact, it did ! Now, @cdw7788 and I took on our personal time to comment on your question. These were "comments" not "answers"; basically advising you to test locally. I have no idea who you are and how much experience you have BTW but that smelt like an XY problem. And thanks, tonight is going to be terrific :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ('office__description',)
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of how this solves the problem?

Comment: "I want to order a model based on a field of its foreign key" => my reply is the correct syntax to do that.

Comment: pczues, after the pedantic, curmudgeonly discussion above, Francois decided to succinctly answer my question completely within 2 lines. As the temporal value "15 seconds" is a theme here, I just typed out his answer and it took me, lo and behold, 15 seconds. This solves the problem of the question I asked, but does not seem to solve mr. Francois's confusion as to why I could not test this in the shell without getting approval from one of the VPs at work, which is really the bigger issue here. Curing cancer > understanding my local project config > ending world hunger, in that order.